# How to setup proxy for dockerfile ADD command

Tags: docker, proxy, dockerfile

I'm trying to download file into the docker image. But my machine is behind proxy.
I can't set proxy paramater for ADD command.
I already tried to set env inside dockerfile.

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://proxy:3128
ENV HTTPS_PROXY https://proxy:3128
```

Also i tried to run docker build with parameters like

```
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy:3128 ...
```

But it didn't help.
Google-ing also didn't give right answer, so i opened this thread.

Comment: ADD command is for copying files from host, how is your network proxy can be involved? or you are downloading file with ADD from url?  - in this case you can use RUN and do WGET with proxy or something else.

Comment: ADD command also can download files for remote urls.

Comment: yeah, i see that in doc, but if you use some console download tool - you can specify proxy manually as workaround

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't found any another option except to put a needed file to local artifactory.
Seems, that is not the good answer. But I don't have another. (

Comment: See my answer; please accept it as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Docker downloads the files specified in the `ADD` instruction and it uses the proxy configured for the Docker daemon itself. I figured it out from experimenting and not from reading the Docker code. You could do that if interested or raise an issue to ask the Docker devs [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues). It makes sense because `ADD` runs on the Docker host whereas `RUN` runs in the container.

`--build-arg` are arguments passed to the container during the build which means the proxy variables you are passing are available in the container's context. You can verify by this by doing `RUN env | grep -i proxy` to print the proxy info or even accessing URLs from behind the proxy in `RUN` instructions when passing `--build-arg`.

To solve the proxy problem with the `ADD` instruction, configure the Docker service itself  by providing the proxy information in the service's Environment property. See detailed instruction at [Control Docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) page.